# bind mount is not working when i run containers in docker-machine

Tags: apache, docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

I was trying to run this code in the machine using docker machine in linux ubuntu 18 using virtual box drivers... but bind mount is not working in vm.. but when i run docker compose run on my machine without using docker machine it works. i want to know why the same bind mount work on local machine and did not work for me on vm.. ?

i tried everything on vm like creating, and deleting everything i could find on the internet.

```
version: '3'

volumes:
  mysql_data:



services:
  web:
    image: php:7.3-apache
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
      - ./apache/conf/000-default.conf:/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

    environment:
      - APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT=/var/www/html/public

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
```

this should work in vm too that i am creating using docker machine..it works on local machine.

```
 volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
      - ./apache/conf/000-default.conf:/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

Comment: This has started happening to me since Docker updated version to 19.x - if you specify an 18.x version when you create the docker machine it will work.

Comment: okay i will do that...  and get back to you as soon as possible..

Comment: Does this suggest the existence of a problem when the host directory is mounted on the VM using `vboxsf` to reach out to *its* host?